# Find a group $G$ that has elements $V$ and $H$ both with order $2$ and the order of $VH$ is $3$.

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples

> Find a group $G$ that has elements $V$ and $H$ both with order $2$ and the order of $VH$ is $3$.

This question appeared on my final and even though it looks like an easy question I had difficulty finding a group.

Comment: A rather flippant answer would be to let $G$ be the group defined by the group presentation $$\langle V, H\mid V^2, H^2, (VH)^3\rangle.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$S_3$ gives such an example: Choose $V = (12)$ and $H = (23)$; then $VH$ is a $3$-cycle, and so has order $3$.

---

As a guide for finding this sort of example, it's immediate that the group cannot be abelian: This would mean that $VH$ has order $2$. The group order must be divisible by both $2$ and $3$, so $S_3$ is the smallest possible example. The next smallest non-abelian group satisfying these order conditions has order $12$.

Comment: Well now I feel stupid. I was only looking at Z D and U.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the symmetries of an equilateral triangle ($D_3$ or $D_6$, depending on choice of notation).  Reflecting across an axis is an operation of order two, but if we reflect over one axis and then a different axis, we get a rotation of the triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Let $G$ be defined by the [group presentation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group) $$\langle V, H\mid V^2, H^2, (VH)^3\rangle.$$ By construction, then, $G$ is of the required form.

Comment: The abelianisation of $G$ is given by $$\begin{align}G^{ab}&=\langle V, H\mid V^2, H^2, V^3H^3\rangle^{ab}\\ &=\langle V, H\mid V^2, H^2, V=V^3=H^{-3}=H^{-1}\rangle^{ab}\\ &=\langle V\mid V^2\rangle\\ &=\Bbb Z_2,\end{align}$$ which does not have an element of order $3$. Hence $G$, as defined in this answer, is not abelian.

Comment: *NB:* The equalities in my previous comment should, in fact, be up to isomorphism only.